# WebLogic SSL Handshake error

Tags: http, ssl, https, weblogic

I'm making a REST call from my WebLogic Java application that receives an SSL handshake error.  I haven't made any special HTTPS or SSL configurations.  The URL is using HTTPS.  If I make the same GET call from a browser on the same server as the application/WebLogic, I get a warning that the connection is untrusted. After hitting accept, I'm able to see the page.  How can I configure WebLogic to allow these connections?

Comment: If you're using SSL, you need to set up certs e.g. you have to set up a "special" SSL configuration. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/security/SetUpSSL.html Have you done that? Are you using the demo certs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to import the certs into my DemoTrust.jks using:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/DemoTrust.jks -alias mycert -file ~/certname.cert
```

I did that for each cert in the chain, which I got from the browser.  I used the default DemoTrust.jks password: DemoTrustKeyStorePassPhrase.  I had also imported the certs to /usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/cacerts, but not sure if that was necessary.